# Can I publish my web app into Google Play and Apple store with Flutter or something else?

Tags: flutter, webview, google-play, app-store

I know there is WebView https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter but I've heard Apple got strict with it recently but is it easy to publish a simple e-shop and website that has a material mobile responsive design to Play store? Apple store? Is the Flutter the quickest way? The web app is pretty straight forward and simple: text/pic content and 2 products to buy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a PWA (progressive web app) for publishing your web app into the Google Play Store and Apple App Store. Converting any web app into PWA takes just less than 5min actually if there's an available high-quality icon file from the designer. You can also just create the icons from the logo with some free online icon generator. Then you will need the manifest JSON which is a simple file to define the name of the app, scope, theme colour and some other "settings." Then you can also create one more file (bit more lines of code) - the service worker if offline use for the app is needed. As you need your app to be also in Google play and Apple Store then of course there's just a non-PWA related hassle to meet all their requirements. You will have to meet the app stores' requirements whatever technology you use: PWA, Flutter or something else. PWA is just a much quicker way compared to Flutter to convert your web app into something that is an app store publishable mobile app.

Some useful resources:

- [About PWAs](https://crnw.uk/pwa)
- [How to turn your web app to PWA](https://tudip.com/blog-post/how-to-turn-a-website-or-web-application-into-pwa-with-example/)
- [The Journey of Publishing a PWA to the App Stores](https://youtu.be/LELAuNihs18?t=1139)

Answer (score 1):

it is possible but it will take time to post since they will check every bug they will decline your request even if the bug is not mandatory hope this helps

Comment: How many hrs of work you think it will be? Quick thing to do?

Comment: @KasparL.Palgi depending on your project minimum 12 hours